# Standard functions defined in header files or automatically linked?

Tags: c, standards

When writing a basic c program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
  printf("program");
}
```

Is the definition of `printf` in "stdio.h" or is the `printf` function automatically linked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually they are automatically linked, but the compiler is allowed to implement them as it pleases (even by compiler magic).

The `#include` is still necessary, because it brings the standard functions into scope.

Comment: How does the magic work?  Is there a way I can achieve the same magic?

Comment: Depends on the compiler.  But why would you want the same magic?

Comment: Just trying to understand why a special case scenario was made for the now standard libraries.  Basically, why did Dennis Ritchie what the magic ;) ?

Comment: @Lime - Dennis Ritchie's C didn't have a lot of magic. They had a `++` operator because the compilers back then didn't know how to optimize `+= 1` to the increment instruction. I suspect all the magic came much later.

Comment: I can only speculate.  I believe there was no standard library in the early days; each system (think mainframes) had its own C library which every programmer could modify.  There was no need for other libraries.   I would guess that separate libraries evolved rather late.  But I repeat: I am speculating here.

Comment: @Chris It is funny that the standards don't follow the reccomended way to code projects (don't define functions in header files)

Comment: @Lime: The magic, when present, is generally because the standard library functions are used everywhere throughout the system, so magical optimizations like "keeping just one copy in memory for all applications to share" have the potential to greatly improve overall system performance. (Of course, lots of testing goes into ensuring that they really *are* optimizations!)

Comment: @Lime: What do you mean by "don't declare functions in header files"?  That's the whole point of headers...

Comment: @ruakh: Of course, every shared library gets the "keeping just one copy in memory for all applications to share" optimization :-)

Comment: @Lime: Normally the standard header files *do* declare functions. (They don't *define* functions -- but it's not recommended for *anyone* to define functions in header files. They should be defined in `.c` files.)

Comment: @Oil meant "define" not "declare" corrected.  Basically whether the functions are linked or defined in header files isn't the point, its that regular users can't achieve the same power, b/c the standard functions are a special case scenario.

Comment: @Lime: Did you mean someone else?

Comment: @Lime: Why do you care?  Normal programmers can create libraries like the standard library.  The only difference is that they have to tell the compiler to link them in.

Comment: @ibid that is one step I wouldn't mind avoiding :) but more importantly I have seen new users get tripped up by including definitions in header files, thinking they are following the "standard"

Answer (score 3):

Usually, in `stdio.h` there's only the prototype; the definition should be inside a library that your object module is automatically linked against (the various msvcrt for VC++ on Windows, libcsomething for gcc on Linux).

By the way, it's `<stdio.h>`, not `"stdio.h"`.

Comment: I believe the library can also be dynamic (for example, GNU libc on Linux).

Comment: Is there anyway to automatically link my own libraries like the compiler does?  Just trying to understand the trickery going on.

Comment: @Lime: if it's possible it's very compiler-specific.

Comment: @Lime - What purpose do you have for wanting to do this?

Comment: @Chris Just trying to understand why a special case scenario was made for the now standard libraries. The "standards" haven't always been standard, therefore there must have been a reason for them to add this functionality.  If it was for strictly convenience, I'm surprised they didn't give the same functionality to general libraries.

Comment: What special case are you talking about? The implicit linking of the C standard library???

Answer (score 1):

Stricto sensu, the compiler and the linker are different things (and I am not sure that the C standard speaks of compilation & linking, it more abstractly speaks of translation and implementation issues).

For instance, on Linux, you often use `gcc` to translate your `hello.c` source file, and `gcc` is a "driving program" which runs the compiler `cc1`, the assembler `as`, the linker `ld` etc.

On Linux, the `<stdio.h>` header is an ordinary file. Run `gcc -v -Wall -H hello.c -o hello` to understand what is happening. The `-v` option asks `gcc` to show you the actual programs (`cc1` and others) that are used. The `-Wall` flag asks for all warnings (don't ignore them!). The `-H` flag asks the compiler to show you the header files which are included.

The header file `/usr/include/stdio.h` is `#include`-ing itself other headers. At some point, the declaration of `printf` is seen, and the compiler parses it and adjust its state accordingly.

Later, the `gcc` command would run the linker `ld` and ask it to link the standard C library (on my system `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so`). This library contains the [object] code of `printf`

I am not sure to understand your question. Reading wikipedia's page about [compilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler), [linkers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29), [linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel), [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_calls) should be useful.

You should not want `gcc` to link automagically your own additional libraries. That would be confusing. (but if you really wanted to do that with GCC, read about [GCC specs file](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options))

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Hmm, I haven't been able to find `cc1` on my system?  Might in have a different name on ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: You do have `cc1` but it is buried in some hard to guess path (it is not, and should not be in your $PATH). Just run `gcc -v` as I suggested, you'll be shown which `cc1` is used.